# can I create shared memory (using CreateFileMapping) in local namespace with the same name?

Tags: c++, windows, ipc

Please can you help me understand whether there can be 2 shared memory objects with the same name in local/global namespace? I know that if we have created a shared memory object first time then we need to call `OpenFileMapping/MapViewOfFile` to open an object. What would happen if I call `CreateFileMapping` on already created object?

e.g.

```
CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
                  NULL,                     // default security 
                  PAGE_READWRITE,           // read/write access
                  0,                        // max. object size 
                  sizeof(BackupData),       // buffer size  
                  "SharedMemory");          // name of mapping object
```

Comment: From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28VS.85%29.aspx): *If the object exists before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing object (with its current size, not the specified size), and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.*

Comment: It is very simple to test, just try it instead of asking.

Comment: Was there a particular part of the documentation that was unclear about what happens in this case?

Comment: @RaymondChen - Got confused by "If the object exists before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing object (with its current size, not the specified size), and GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS." We don't call GetLastError() before opening (MapViewFile) the object. So was wondering if it returns an existing object handle and also there is an error then would MapViewFile work?

Comment: If you don't call `GetLastError` before `MapViewOfFile` then you won't know what `GetLastError` returned. `CreateFileMapping` cannot predict the future. It doesn't know whether you're going to call `GetLastError` or not. The documentation is saying "If the object exists before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing object, and *if you bothered to call `GetLastError`* if would return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`." Can you suggest what changes could be made to the documentation to prevent others from being confused the same way you were?

Comment: @RaymondChen - Yes, I agree GetLastError should be called after CreateFileMapping but you cannot expect in the real world scenario that CreateFileMapping is always followed by GetLastError. Also, most of the time you are working on someone else's code. Unless there is an issue you wouldn't want to modify it. Regarding the documentation, in my personal opinion, it would be clearer if specified that the call succeeds (or at least specify that MapViewFile would work if size is not modified)

Comment: The case where the file mapping already exists is a mixed success/failure case. It succeeded in creating a handle ("the function returns a handle") but it also failed to create a new object (since the object already exists). So the documentation can't say that the call "succeeds" in that case (it is only a partial success). The return value of `GetLastError` lets you distinguish this case, if you care. Most people don't care and just check the handle, which is fine if you are okay with reusing an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28VS.85%29.aspx) for `CreateFileMapping` tells you exactly what you need to know:

[image: msdn]

So you *cannot* use the same name in the same namespace (Global or Local). You can't even use the same name for different types of kernel objects.

If you try to create a new file mapping with the same name as an existing file mapping, it will attempt to open the existing file mapping (subject to your page protection attributes). If this is successful, you *will* get a handle to the existing object, but you will also get a return value of **ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS** from `GetLastError`.

If you think about it logically, the only way you can share a file mapping between processes is to use the same name, so it's pointless to have two *different* mappings with the same name!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Completely agree that there isn't any point in creating the shared object with the same name. Just to clarify, if I don't call GetLastError and assume that the handle returned is of opened object then will MapViewFile work?

Comment: @HVar yes, as long as it respects the size of the originally created mapping and not the size you specified when "opening" it.

Comment: What is the solution then if we want to use CreateFileMapping in an application that needs to run for users without administrator privilege?